# cfselect - how to dynamically set the selected option value w/ manual values?

Tags: coldfusion

If I have a select setup with with hard manual values and I want to set one of the options below as the default value based on that, how would you go about it?    Like when this form is reached theres a variable that will contain 1 through 12.  So if it's "6" I'd like to make "6 months" the selected value.    I know you can put "selected = "selected"" directly in the option values but I don't see how to get an if statement in there.   I tried doing it a few was in the cfselect and couldn't figure out anything that worked.

Thanks!

```
<cfselect name="months_select" id="months_select" multiple="no">                                                
    <option value="1">1 Month</option>                                                                                              
    <option value="2">2 Months</option>
    <option value="3">3 Months</option>
    <option value="4">4 Months</option>
    <option value="5">5 Months</option>
    <option value="6">6 Months</option>                                                                                                 
    <option value="7">7 Months</option>
    <option value="8">8 Months</option>
    <option value="9">9 Months</option>
    <option value="10">10 Months</option>
    <option value="11">11 Months</option>
    <option value="12">12 Months</option>   
</cfselect>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can embed the CF directly into the HTML, I've done the first one as an example.

```
<select name="months_select" id="months_select" multiple="no">

    <option value="1" <cfif YourVariable EQ 1>selected="selected"</cfif>>1 Month</option>
    <option value="2">2 Months</option>
    <option value="3">3 Months</option>
    <option value="4">4 Months</option>
    <option value="5">5 Months</option>
    <option value="6">6 Months</option>                                                                                                 
    <option value="7">7 Months</option>
    <option value="8">8 Months</option>
    <option value="9">9 Months</option>
    <option value="10">10 Months</option>
    <option value="11">11 Months</option>
    <option value="12">12 Months</option>   
</select>
```

You're better off making a loop though.

```
<select name="months_select" id="months_select" multiple="no">
    <cfloop from="1" to="12" index="Month"> 
        <option value="#Month#" <cfif YourVariable EQ Month>selected="selected"</cfif>>#Month# Month<cfif Month GT 1>s</cfif></option>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: use a loop assuming of course there is a cfoutput surrounding the cfselect. You can also use ternary if  <option value = "#month#" #month eq month(now()) ? 'selected="selected"':''#>

Comment: Needing cfoutput should be a given. Ternary is only ACF9+ and since the OP didn't say which version he had, it was omitted.

Comment: Correct about CF9, I should have added that. :)  Considering it's a beginner question thinking code between <cfselect> and </cfselect> wouldn't need a cfoutput tag is reasonable (like cfmail).  Also, I don't see any reason in this code to use cfselect. a simple html select would work and not generate any extra CF javascript.

Comment: Fair enough point on the cfselect, I had just copied them from their example, but removed them now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `cfselect` and generating your options with a query, you can define the default value there.

```
<cfselect 
  name="months_select" 
  id="months_select" 
  multiple="no" 
  query="numMonths" 
  selected="#monthSelected#" 
  value="monthValue"></cfselect>
```

Comment: Using a query for a simple 1-12 loop seems a bit overkill.

Comment: True enough, but a future reader may be using `cfselect` for a bigger project.